# Getting firebase reference out of SingleValueEventListener

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using `SingleValueEventListener` to get some data from Firebase Database. Having acquired the data, I need to get another Firebase database reference using that data. Later, I need to use the second/new Firebase database ref inside different method.

When I use this second reference, I am getting null object reference exception. 
Here is the code. It is from onCreate():

```
 mCurrentUserDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String university = dataSnapshot.child("university").getValue().toString();
            String groupid = dataSnapshot.child("groupid").getValue().toString();
            //Having acquired university and group ID, now we can get reference to group members list
            mMembersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Universities").child(university).child("Groups").child(groupid).child("Members");
```

And, I need to use this mMembersDatabase again in onStart() method. How can i do this? Please dont suggest to get the ref inside onStart(). I need to know how can i pass the ref from one method to another method.

Comment: if there are many universities then you will need to do it inside a foreach loop. show a screenshot of your firebase structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `null` because `onDataChange()` method is called asynccrounus. It means that is called even before you getting the data from the database. To use the value of your `mMembersDatabase` outside `onDataChange()` method you need to create your own callback.

To achieve this, first you need to create an `interface` like this:

```
public interface MyCallback {
    void onCallback(DatabaseReference databaseReference);
}
```

Then you need to create a method that is actually getting the data from the database. This method should look like this:

```
public void readData(MyCallback myCallback) {
    mCurrentUserDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String university = dataSnapshot.child("university").getValue().toString();
            String groupid = dataSnapshot.child("groupid").getValue().toString();
            //Having acquired university and group ID, now we can get reference to group members list
            mMembersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Universities").child(university).child("Groups").child(groupid).child("Members");
            myCallback.onCallback(mMembersDatabase);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
```

In the end, in your `onStart()` method, just simply call `readData()` method and pass `MyCallback` as an argument like this:

```
readData(new MyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCallback(DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        //use the value of your databaseReference
    }
});
```

This is the only way in which you can use that value outside `onDataChange()` method. For more information please see my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774).

Comment: Thank you! It is working great. I have also visited the link you provided. Great explanation!

Comment: I also wanted to ask, what if, I want to pass this mMembersDatabase reference as a parameter to FirebaseRecyclerAdapter? How can I achieve this?

Comment: You're welcome! You need to use it in the same way. When you are calling the `readData()` method, inside the `onCallback()` method, pass the `databaseReference` object to the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: I am afraid i did not get what you meant. Could you explain once again?

Comment: `databaseReference` is available inside the `onCallback()` method. Now, take this `databaseReference` object in pass it to the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` constructor. That's it.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to create the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` inside the `onCallback()`? I tried this but it is not working.

Comment: I cannot give you a solution having only the code above which you provided for the initial question. So, this is basically another question. So i suggest you post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you. Don't forget to add a [mcv](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to create data class:

```
public class UniversityData {

    String university;
    String groupId;

    public String getUniversity() {
        return university;
    }

    public void setUniversity(String university) {
        this.university = university;
    }

    public String getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(String groupid) {
        this.groupId = groupid;
    }
}
```

Using this class you can parse all result from firebase to your activity.
Then you need to create your custom listener **interface** which listens if new data was received:

```
public interface DataListener<DATA> {
    void onDataReceived(DATA data);
}
```

Then use data class in your firebase data receiver:

```
    public void getUniversityData(final DataListener<UniversityData> listener) {
        final UniversityData[] dataArray = new UniversityData[1];
        DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (snapshot!=null) {
                        //String university = dataSnapshot.child("university").getValue().toString();
                        //String groupid = dataSnapshot.child("groupid").getValue().toString();
                        dataArray[0] = snapshot.getValue(UniversityData.class);
                    }
                }
                listener.onDataReceived(dataArray[0]);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        });
    }
```

Then in your activity implement created data listener:

```
public class MainPage extends AppCompatActivity implements DataListener<UniversityData> {

    @Override
    public void onDataReceived(UniveristyData data) {
        String university = data.getUniversity();
        String groupid = data.getGroupid();
    }
}
```

And that's all. Now you can use your received data in your activity from created listener.

To call method in activity which implements listener use `getUniversityData(this);`

Hope it helps.